# Select unique entries showing at least one value from another column

Tags: r, filtering, subset

I have the following dataset (32000 entries) of water chemical compounds annual means organized by monitoring sites and sampling year:

```
data= data.frame(Site_ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Year=c(1976, 1977, 1978, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2003, 2004, 2005), AnnualMean=c(1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.1, 2.6, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6, 1.9))
```

```
Site_ID    Year    AnnualMean
1          1976    1.1
1          1977    1.2
1          1978    1.1
2          2004    2.1
2          2005    2.6
2          2006    3.1
3          2003    2.7
3          2004    2.6
3          2005    1.9
```

I would like to select the data only from all monitoring sites showing at least a measurement in 2005 in their time range. With the above dataset, the expect output dataset would be:

```
Site_ID    Year    AnnualMean
2          2004    2.1
2          2005    2.6
2          2006    3.1
3          2003    2.7
3          2004    2.6
3          2005    1.9
```

I am completely new in R and have been spinning my head around with data manipulation, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Site_ID) %>%
  filter(2005 %in% Year)
```

Comment: And this is why `dplyr` is so elegant. This would be a base R way of doing it. `data[data$Site_ID %in% data[data$Year %in% 2005,]$Site_ID,]`

Comment: As a small revision to my question, how should I write the filter request to only select the data from monitoring sites that have at least 10 measurements between 1990 and 2005 ? I tried `filter(n()>=10 %in% between(phenomenonTimeReferenceYear, 1990, 2012))` without success. Thank you !

Comment: That's quite a bit different - I'd recommend a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, using `subset` + `ave`

```
dfout <- subset(df,!!ave(Year,Site_ID,FUN = function(x) "2005" %in% x))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Site_ID Year AnnualMean
4       2 2004        2.1
5       2 2005        2.6
6       2 2006        3.1
7       3 2003        2.7
8       3 2004        2.6
9       3 2005        1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[2005 %in% Year], Site_ID]
```